# React-native retrieve method return value of another class

Tags: react-native, methods, return-value

I am trying to receive the return value of a method in another class with react-native.

ClassA.js

```
export default class ClassA{
    send(query) {
    var value = 1+query;
    return value;
  }
}
```

Trying to get value from class App.js

```
var value = ClassA.send(query);
```

This doesn't work however.
I am receiving the following error:

> ClassA.default.send is not a function, '_ClassA.default.send' is undefined

Comment: How are you importing `ClassA`?

Comment: @JoseVf import ClassA from './ClassA';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add static keyword to use as a class method,

```
export default class ClassA{
    static send(query) {
      var value = 1+query;
      return value;
    }
}
```

so you can access it with,

```
var value = ClassA.send(query);
```

or you can use it as a instance method;

```
export default class ClassA{
   send(query) {
     var value = 1+query;
     return value;
   }
}
```

and in this situation you can access that method from instance;

```
var instance = new ClassA();
var value = instance.send(query);
```